Should we cache all static assets on the web?
Should all static assets, such as fonts, images, and JavaScript files, be cached on the client?
I can imagine that if you visit many websites, your storage will quickly fill up with assets that might never be used again. This is particularly true because we typically add a cache header similar to this: Cache-control: max-age=31536000. Or, is it more up to the user-agent to determine whether or not to keep it in the cache for this long?
